# CLuster Manager not updated in map

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to cluster some points in my application map, It work prefect for first time and data clustered but when try to update the list again with new data not change happen and clusters still exist I try to use `clearItems()`, `clear()` map but no change happen the following is my code for it can any one help please.

Code for map

```
((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLngBounds ADELAIDE = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(16.57946, 35.69014), new LatLng(31.67252, 50.20833));
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(ADELAIDE);
        final LatLng location = new LatLng(mDefaultLat, mDefaultLng);
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(getContext(), mMap);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(new ClusterRenderer(getContext(), mMap, mClusterManager));
        final CameraPosition[] mPreviousCameraPosition = {null};
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                CameraPosition position = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
                mDefaultLat = position.target.latitude;
                mDefaultLng = position.target.longitude;
                locationFromMap = true;
                populate();
                if (mPreviousCameraPosition[0] == null || mPreviousCameraPosition[0].zoom != position.zoom) {
                    mPreviousCameraPosition[0] = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
                    addItems();
                }
            }
        });
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 16));

            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                try {
                    new OfficeDialog(mActivity, officeList.get(Integer.parseInt(marker.getSnippet()))).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
});
```

addItems function

```
private void addItems() {
    if (!listAdded && officeList.size() > 0) {
        mClusterManager.clearItems();
        mClusterManager.cluster();
        mClusterManager.addItems(officeList);
        listAdded = true;
    }
    mClusterManager.cluster();
}
```

and my cluster manager custom render

```
public class ClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Office> {
    Context context;
    private IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private float density;



    public ClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<Office> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        clusterManager.setRenderer(this);
        this.context = context;
        density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(Office item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ejar_location_icon_copy));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<Office> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        if(iconGenerator == null) {
            iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
            iconGenerator.setContentView(makeTextView(context));
        }
        iconGenerator.setBackground(makeBackground(false, cluster.getSize()));

        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize()))));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterRendered(Cluster<Office> cluster, Marker marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<Office> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }

    private ShapeDrawable makeBackground(boolean isClicked, int size) {
        ShapeDrawable background = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary);
        if (size < 50) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary);
        } else if (size < 100) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cluster_50);
        } else if (size < 200) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cluster_100);
        } else if (size < 1000) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cluster_200);
        } else color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cluster_1000);

        background.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        return background;
    }

    private SquareTextView makeTextView(Context context) {
        SquareTextView squareTextView = new SquareTextView(context);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
        squareTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        squareTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        squareTextView.setId(com.google.maps.android.R.id.text);
        int twelveDpi = (int) (12.0F * density);
        squareTextView.setPadding(twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi);
        return squareTextView;
    }

    public IconGenerator getIconGenerator(boolean isClicked) {
        iconGenerator.setBackground(makeBackground(isClicked, 0));
        return iconGenerator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debug and search about this issue I didn't found any reason about it so after check my web service I found the issue on it.
Web service return static locations for my objects so the clusters not changed after fix it the application works correctly without any issues.